# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteScalar()'

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I'm working with a local database in a Windows Form Application. It works like charm, but I wanted to check if a record that a user searchs for is in the dataBase. I wrote the following code, but I get an error and I can't figure out how to solve it. I know that I reference a non-static object to a static method. But didn't know how to solve it. Thank in advance !

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    var connString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Stellwag\Stellwag\Angajati.sdf";
                    using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var numePrenume = textBox1.Text.Trim().Split(' ');
                            var nume = numePrenume[0];
                            var prenume = numePrenume[1];
                            conn.Open();
                            var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info WHERE Nume='" + nume + "' AND Prenume='" + prenume + "'";
                            var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
                            var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
                            var dataTable = new DataTable();
                            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                            int userCount = (int) SqlCeCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                            if (userCount > 0)
                            {
                                Info form = new Info(nume, prenume);
                                form.Show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Nu exista un angajat cu acest nume");
                            }


                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }

                    }
            }
```

Comment: I think the `dataAdapter.Fill` is enough to grab the information and you don't need to manually execute the command, but I haven't worked with that for a long time. Anyway, to solve the actual error, change `SqlCeCommand.ExecuteScalar()` to `command.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Now I get error at parsing the query..

Comment: Remome second `*` from query: `SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM ...`

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your `SqlCeCommand` object, not the class itself. Just change your

```
int userCount = (int)SqlCeCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

to

```
int userCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

A few things more;

- You have an extra `*` after your `COUNT(*)`. Remove it.
- You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your command and adapter automatically as you did for your connection.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `int userCount = (int) SqlCeCommand.ExecuteScalar();` with

```
int userCount = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

because `SqlCeCommand` is a class and `ExecuteScalar()` is a non-static method of that class. so you cannot access `ExecuteScalar()` without a reference. in this statement `var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);` you are creating a reference to that class so you can call `ExecuteScalar()` through this reference.

Comment: Thank u. Got it now !